# elementNodeReference.children doesn't detect text nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Per [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Element.children%20elementNodeReference.children) returns a list of child nodes. In my testing this seems to ignore text nodes. Is this correct?

What seems baffling to me is that firstChild works but the children list is zero.

Tested in Firefox 20.0.1.

Here's my test code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<title></title>
<script>

function checktable() {
    var mytable = document.getElementById("mytable");

    var cells = mytable.rows[0].cells;

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        console.log("firstChild.nodeValue:", cells[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
        console.log("firstChild.data:",cells[i].firstChild.data);
        console.log("children.length:",cells[i].children.length);
    }
}


function checkdiv() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    console.log("firstChild.nodeValue:", mydiv.firstChild.nodeValue);
    console.log("firstChild.data:",mydiv.firstChild.data);
    console.log("children.length:",mydiv.children.length);
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table id="mytable">
<tr>
<td>Blob</td>
<td>Blab</td>
<td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="mydiv">
Blib
</div>

<button onclick="checktable()">Check table</button>
<button onclick="checkdiv()">Check div</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.childNodes), not [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Element.children).

The former is a method of `Node` and lists child nodes. The latter is a method of `Element` and consequently lists child elements, which is preferable in some situations.